# Run all iterations in a for loop in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-2.2

I am using Python v 2.2.1 and trying to write a code which needs to perform some tasks in parallel inside a for loop. The number of iterations is not fixed and depends on the list (`serverList`, in this case). How can I achieve this through multithreading or multiprocessing. I read through some examples but they were calling different functions in parallel. Here I need to call the same function (`shutdownTask`), but with different arguments. Part of the code is given below:

```
try:
    <some code>
    for server in serverList:
        print ('Shutting down server: '+server+'...')
        shutdownTask(server, serverType)
finally:
    verifyStatus()
```

Comment: Have you tried [Pykka](https://www.pykka.org/en/latest/) ?

Comment: Python v 2.2.1? Really? Because that is ancient.

Comment: Any reason you are using a 13 year old version of python?

Comment: Looking at the print function (and its parentheses), you might have meant Python v 3.2.1. Though I would still recommend to upgrade to the current version (3.4).

Comment: The [introduction on Pythons multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) gives a very simple example of calling the same function in parallel with different arguments. You can adapt that to your needs.

Comment: follow [pep-8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) unless you have a *specific* reason not to.

Comment: ITt is 2.2.1 and yes i get that a lot.. it is part of the product so i cannot upgrade it and cannot install additional frameworks in this. So i was looking for something which comes built-in

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). You could launch one task per server in background.

To create a task you decorate your function using the `@task` decorator.

To run a task you use the `delay()` method added to the decorated task function.

*Note: I don't know if there may be compatibility issues if you are really using the very old Python version 2.2.1*

**UPDATE**

If you don't need such a complex solution, then you could go with [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) class.

Comment: Why install the whole Celery framework when possibly the built-in  multiprocessing module can do this?

Comment: If you are creating quite a big system, Celery is a good choice. You can monitor the state of your tasks and manage them in a quite easy way. However, if it's a simple task and you don't require any management you could go through `threading`

Comment: I don't see any indication of a big system in the question, so I'd start small.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a process (or a thread) pool (assuming you meant Python 3.2 version):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def shutdown(server):
    try:
        shutdownTask(server, serverType)
    except Exception as e:
        return server, str(e)
    else:
        return server, None

try:
    <some code>
    pool = Pool()
    for server, error in pool.imap_unordered(shutdown, serverList):
        if error is None:
            print('Done shutting down server:', server, '...')
        else:
            print('Error shutting down server:', server, '...', error)
finally:
    verifyStatus()
```

Comment: [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing) is "new in version 2.6".

Comment: @PeterWood: Python **3.2**

Comment: @PeterWood: read the comments under the question. 2.2 is likely a mistake. It is not even clear how one would install such ancient version

Comment: The comments under the question verify that it is 2.2.1.